Is there a way to force ignore a date value in the dashboard filters?
I'm currently working on a dashboard, on Apache Superset 4.0, with multiple and diverse date range.
I need precise filtering so I use jinja templating, which enables me to select the date range on which I'm filtering depending on the chart.
Sadly, when applying a date filter on the dashboard, it automatically detect any date range in your virtual dataset to apply it. I do need some date values to make my chart so they are detected in the filter and filtering applies on it, when it is not a variable I want to be filtered.
As I'm already using jinja templating to filtering the date value on my own, and applying it to the date value I want so it feels redundant, inefficient and can produce false results.
I tried to modify the settings in the virtual dataset, saying it's a non-filterable values, tweaking multiples settings but I got no positive results on that.
The only way I found was "disguising" my date value with sql queries to make it non-datetime values in my virtual datasets but some case are making it pretty difficult to do it and my dashboard loses flexibility...
Thank you for your help

This may be too simple a solution, but can you edit the dashboard filters -> scoping and stop the filter from applying to those charts where you are already using that date value with Jinja?

Sadly, excluding the chart with the scoping parameters also stops jinja from taking in the parameter to filter it... Thank you for your help
